# SMO DependencyWalker, Many-to-Many relation problem

Tags: c#, sql-server, code-generation, smo

I'm trying to discover the database structure, to generate some kind of POCOs,

I used this snippet to discover the related tables,

```
var result = new ArrayList();
DependencyWalker w = new DependencyWalker(server);      
DependencyTree tree = w.DiscoverDependencies(new SqlSmoObject[]{tbl}, DependencyType.Children);
DependencyCollection depends = w.WalkDependencies(tree);

foreach (DependencyCollectionNode dcn in depends)
{
    //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show( tbl.Name + " -> " +  dcn.Urn.Parent);           
    if (dcn.Urn.Type == "Table" && dcn.Urn.GetNameForType("Table") != tbl.Name)
    {
        var tblName = dcn.Urn.GetNameForType("Table");
        result.Add(tblName);
    }
}

return result;
```

this works fine for every table in the database, except those has `Many-to-Many` relation

for example

```
Car

CarColor

Employee

CarOwnerHistory
```

in `CarOwnerHistory`, i've a relation to both `Car`, and `Employee`, every `Car` has a `CarColor`,

although `CarColor` has nothing to do with `CarOwnerHistory`, the `DependencyCollection` for it get a reference to `CarOwnerHistory`

this is the generated code

```
public class Car {
  public virtual IList<CarOwner> CarOwner { get; set; }
  public virtual CarColor CarColor { get; set; }
}

public class CarColor {  
  public virtual IList<CarOwner> CarOwner { get; set;}  //:( Why ???
  public virtual IList<Car> Car { get; set;}    
}

public class CarOwner {
  public virtual Car Car { get; set; }
  public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }                                
}
```

is this a bug? if so, is there any work around ??

Answer (score 1):

This link may prove helpful if you are creating a mapping of tables. I have not use POCO objects with LINQ as I prefer to create my on domain objects for simple things. Here is a URL that may be helpful. I used this one for order of deletetions, or rather helping purge a database once.

http://www.jasinskionline.com/technicalwiki/Default.aspx?Page=List-Tables-in-Dependency-Order-SQL-Server&NS=&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1